# Mostrar datos de una consulta de SQL Server en una vista de MVC.Net

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto MVC.Net en C#, en dónde debo mostrar la siguiente información dentro de una tarjeta en una vista.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muestro lo que he trabajado hasta el momento:

Modelo

```
public class TarjetasInformativas
{
    public string PrimerNombre { get; set; }
    public decimal PrimerMonto { get; set; }
}
```

Modelo dónde hago conexión a mi base de datos

```
public class DatosTarjetasInformativas
{
    public List<TarjetasInformativas> RetornarNombres()
    {
        List<TarjetasInformativas> objTarjetas = new List<TarjetasInformativas>();

        using(SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=HN123; Initial Catalog=DBPRUEBA; Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            string query = "SP_TARJETASINFORMATIVAS";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            sqlConnection.Open();

            using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    objTarjetas.Add(new TarjetasInformativas()
                    {
                        PrimerNombre = dr["ENTIDADES"].ToString(),
                        PrimerMonto = decimal.Parse(dr["MONTO"].ToString()),
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        return objTarjetas;
    }
}
```

Controlador

```
 public ActionResult ObtenerNombres()
    {
        DatosTarjetasInformativas objDTTarjetas = new DatosTarjetasInformativas();

        List<TarjetasInformativas> objTarjetas = objDTTarjetas.RetornarNombres();

        return View(objTarjetas);
    }
```

Vista

```
@model WebPlantillaOpexLTE.Models.TarjetasInformativas
<div class="col-lg-3 col-6">
                <!-- small box -->
                <div class="small-box bg-info">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <h3>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.PrimerNombre)</h3>

                        <p>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.PrimerMonto)</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="icon">
                        <i class="ion ion-android-locate"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>
```

He puesto un punto de interrupción en el método dónde conecto la base de datos en mi proyecto. Al momento que llamo al método de mi controlador dentro de la url "Home/ObtenerNombres", como pueden ver me recorre la información de mi procedimiento almacenado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi problema es que al cargar la vista la tarjeta aparece con las variables que declare dentro de mi modelo, y no con el valor de ellas que es lo que busco.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría saber que podría hacer para que la tarjeta de mi vista me sea visible con la consulta que realice en un principio, en lugar de PrimerNombre, "453 - Operaciones I Series" y en lugar de PrimerMonto el valor de 7219.19. ¿Qué debería cambiar?

Comment: Esto `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.PrimerNombre)` cámbialo por esto `@Model.PrimerNombre` y lo mismo para el monto

Comment: He intentado como sugieres, pero me genera la excepción System.NullReferenceException.

Comment: En qué parte aparece ese error?

Comment: Justamente en esa línea de código, dónde pongo <h3>@Model.PrimerNombre</h3>

Answer (score 0):

creo que el problema esta en que desde el controlador estas enviando una lista y en la vista estas recibiendo solo un objeto, tu primera línea debería ser

```
@model List<WebPlantillaOpexLTE.Models.TarjetasInformativas>
```

y no

```
@model WebPlantillaOpexLTE.Models.TarjetasInformativas
```

o desde el controlador no enviarlo como lista
o en tu vista crear un ciclo para recorrer cada item de tu lista y mostrar el valor por pantalla, espero aun sirva

Comment: He probado como sugieres, en la definición del model como también ir iterando en un ciclo for each, me genera la siguiente excepción System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>.Model.get returned null, ¿crees que el problema siga estando en la vista o dentro del controlador o modelo pueda que tengo algo mal?

Comment: según lo que muestras en tu punto de interrupción, si estas obteniendo tus datos desde tu controlador, entonces el problema debe estar en la vista ya que estas pasando la lista a través del view() y hasta ahí todo se ve bien, lo que podrías hacer para probar en la vista es mantener la definición @model List<WebPlantillaOpexLTE.Models.TarjetasInformativas> ya que estas pasando una lista y hacer un <h1>@Model.Count</h1> y ver si te cuenta los registros de tu lista, si te muestra un error podrías probar pasando los datos a través de un ViewBag y no como parámetro a la vista.